# Safari loses context of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, safari, webgl

I have a WebGL context, that is created like this:

```
<section id="main_section">
        <article id="GL">
            <canvas id="GL-Surface">

            </canvas>
        </article>
</section>
```

and I resize it with these lines:

```
document.getElementById("GL-Surface").style.width  = w + "px";
document.getElementById("GL-Surface").style.height = h + "px";

document.getElementById("GL-Surface").width  = w;
document.getElementById("GL-Surface").height = h;

gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
```

This works on all browser, but sometimes fails in Safari with this message:

```
[Error] WebGL: CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL: loseContext: context lost
```

How can I prevent that?

Comment: you need to leave more info. There are 1000s, maybe even 10000s of webgl examples that resize the canvas and don't lose the context so your question does not have enough info to tell what you're doing differently than everyone else.

Comment: @gman this is all the code for scaling I use, I cant show more code, because there isn't any